# MKMapView into UIScrollView leads to memory issue after several times of scrolling

Tags: ios, memory, uiscrollview, mkmapview

I want to use one `UIViewController` with a horizontal `UIScrollView` in it to display two pages. The first page is a `UITableView` which contains multiple cells. The other page contains a `MKMapView`. Both, the table and the map are loaded from a `.xib` file into the controller. The problem is when scrolling from one page to the other and back several times the app starts lagging and eventually crashes. In the console I get this message 4 times for each time scrolling to the 'map-page':

```
ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-
1230.34.9.30.27/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1763: InfoLog 
SolidRibbonShader:
ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-
1230.34.9.30.27/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1764: WARNING: Output of vertex 
shader 'v_gradient' not read by fragment shader
```

The last message before the app crashes is this one:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

I also noticed that the map reloads each time I scroll to the map-page. 
When I replace the map with some static content the app runs perfectly smooth. 
I think the problem is that the map reloads each time you scroll to the map-page. 
I just dropped the `MKMapView` in the view of the .xib file without modifying anything or giving it a class.

Maybe there is something to prevent the map from reloading it each time if it isn't necessary which may solve this problem.